# Running report from Task/Job Scheduler

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I'm trying to run a report that execute some SQL queries in NAV 2015

If I run the report manually it's working perfectly, but when I set it into the Task Scheduler it give error as it has an automation that is trying to load in the client.

I've changed the **CREATE** parameters to (FALSE, FALSE) instead of (FALSE, TRUE) so it runs in Server instead of Client, but when I try to compile it will give this error:

[image]

**Translation:** Cannot create an automation object "sqlConnection" in NAV Server. You must create it in Client.

But if I create it in client CREATE(FALSE, TRUE) it will give error:
[image]

**Translation:** NAV Server was trying to return a Client call to create an automation object. Call returns from Client are not allowed in NAV Server.

This is the code: (Looping Company table)

```
IF (STRPOS(LOWERCASE(Company.Name), 'prueba') = 0) AND (STRPOS(LOWERCASE(Company.Name), 'test') = 0) AND (STRPOS(LOWERCASE(Company.Name), 'uat') = 0) AND (STRPOS(LOWERCASE(Company.Name), 'prova') = 0) THEN BEGIN
  recWasteHeader.CHANGECOMPANY(Company.Name);
  IF recWasteHeader.COUNT > 0 THEN BEGIN
    recWasteLine.SETRANGE("Document Type", 4);
    recWasteLine.SETRANGE("Business Type", 2);
    recWasteLine.SETFILTER("Sub Contract No.", '<>%1', '*NUL*');
    IF recWasteLine.FINDSET THEN BEGIN
      IF ISCLEAR(sqlConnection) THEN
        CREATE(sqlConnection, FALSE, FALSE);
      sqlConnection.Open(ConnectionString);

      IF ISCLEAR(sqlCommand) THEN
        CREATE(sqlCommand, FALSE, FALSE);
      sqlCommand.ActiveConnection := sqlConnection;                      
      sqlCommand.CommandText := 'DELETE FROM [Noc Services Price] WHERE Empresa=' + q + Company.Name + q;
      sqlCommand.CommandType := 1;
      sqlCommand.Execute;

      REPEAT
        querydata := STRSUBSTNO(dataset, Company.Name, recWasteLine."Document No.", recWasteLine."Line No.", recWasteLine.Amount);
        sqlCommand.CommandText := 'INSERT INTO [Noc Services Price] (Empresa, Contracte, [Linea contracte], [PREU ACTUAL]) VALUES ( ' + querydata + ');';
        sqlCommand.Execute;
      UNTIL recWasteLine.NEXT = 0;

      sqlConnection.Close;      
    END;
  END;
END;
```

I also can't find the dotnet System.Data.SqlClient

[image]

Comment: What type is `sqlConnection`? And what Nav/BC version are you using?

Comment: Most probably you need to use .net instead of an automation type.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it's a NAV 2015.. sqlConnection is Automation:'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library'.Connection

Comment: Then use Ado.Net instead. It’ll run on server.

Comment: should I make my own dll or there's a dotnet for it already in NAV defaults? thank you by advance @MakSim

Comment: I think it should be available on windows by default througt .NET framework. Something like this `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

Comment: I don't have the dotnet System.Data.SqlClient group, I updated the question with a screenshot of my dotnets